Why did the IRS refund me the penalty?
Assumptions (Normal w2 job, index fund investments with dividends but no taxes witheld no other weird financial products),  For FY23, I had $56,472 owed and $47,392 paid thus requiring having to pay $9,255 at tax time (includes the $175 penalty as calculated as a percentage of the underpayment for not having 90% taxes paid). But i got a check in the mail from the IRS with the $175 overpayment.
The penalty was automatically added with Turbotax since it determined I needed to pay it. Any stipulation that I/it missed to make the penalty not apply to me?

What were your taxes the year before? There is a 100% or 110% safe harbor when compared with the previous year.

How much was your previous year's tax? I believe/suspect having paid 100% of the previous year's tax will escape a penalty.

FY22 was Owed 43278 and paid 38201 and ended up paying a 30 dollar penalty but i didn't get that penalty refunded last year.

Do you know if you need to meet the 100% or the 110% safe harbor? You need to meet the 110% safe harbor if your adjusted gross income (AGI) for 2022 was more than $150,000 ($75,000 if your 2022 filing status was married filing separately). Otherwise you need to meet the 100% safe harbor.

Yeah i checked all those numbers, i don't qualify for the safe habor, where i live wasn't in a disaster zone and i'm not a fisherman/farmer.

I checked my Tax Transcripts and it has these 2 codes if it helps.
971 Notice issued 03-11-2024 $0.00
846 Refund issued 03-01-2024 $175.00


For FY23, i ha 56472 owed and 47392 paid thus requiring having to pay
9255 at tax time (includes the 175 penalty as calculated as a
percentage of the underpayment for not having 90% taxes paid). But i
got a check in the mail from the irs with the 175 overpayment.

from the comments:

Q: What were your taxes the year before? There is a 100% or 110% safe
harbor when compared with the previous year.
A: Owed 43278 and paid 38201 and ended up paying a 30 dollar penalty but
i didn't get that refunded last year

The previous year you were responsible for $43,278. The 110% safe harbor goal would be $47,605.80. It appears that you just missed the 110% safe harbor goal by $214.
If your AGI the previous year was less than $150,000  then you would use the 100% safe harbor, which you easily met.
I would check that the correct numbers for last year were used by the tax software.

Yeah this is weird, i double check the numbers are the seem to be correct and i don't see my area listed on a disaster declared area for relief.

I checked my Tax Transcripts and it has these 2 codes if it helps.
971 Notice issued 03-11-2024 $0.00
846 Refund issued 03-01-2024 $175.00

Note that this may mean that the IRS caught a filing error in your favor that was sufficient to bring you under the safe harbor line. I'm not sure if there is a way to confirm that.
